# an integral inequality about Lebsegue measurable functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let both $f:[0,1]\to (0,\infty)$ and $g:[0,1]\to (-\infty,0)$ be Lebsegue measurable functions.Show the following inequality:
$$\int^1_0 f(s)ds\int^1_0 g(t)dt\leq\int^1_0 f(x)g(x)dx.$$
It can be deduced by $$\int^1_0 f(x)\frac{g(x)}{\int^1_0 g(t)dt}dx\leq\int^1_0 f(x)dx.$$
But how to prove the second inequality by Jensen inequality which I think a sufficient way?

Comment: That's the second inequality.But how to prove the second inequality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't prove it, because it's not true:

Let $f(x) = 2x$ and $g(x) = -f(x)$. Then

$$\int_0^1 f(s)\,ds \int_0^1 g(t)\, dt = 1\cdot (-1) > -\frac{4}{3} = \int_0^1 f(x)g(x)\, dx.$$